# Getting the correct sizes for JComponent after using GroupLayout

Tags: java, size, layout-manager, grouplayout

I wanted to ask whether it is possible to get the correct sizes of an JPanel after it has been placed in another JPanel that uses GroupLayout as Layout Manager. I have already tried to use:

.getPreferredSize(): this results in the Preferred Size that has been set by me, not the actual size that is drawn on the JPanel in the frame (if frame get's resized, the element will expand horizontally; which is not seen in the values).

.getSize(): it returns 0.

.getHeight(): it returns 0.

.getWidth(): it returns 0.

Maybe the positioning of the code is relevant, but it is executed AFTER shown on screen so it should not matter.

To force it to do that after it is shown on screen, maybe I can use EventQueue, but I'm not sure how.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the "correct" size of the component only after it has been rendered, either by calling pack or setVisible(true) on the top level container.

> Maybe the positioning of the code is relevant, but it is executed AFTER shown on screen so it should not matter.

Then something's not right. Are you sure that you're calling these methods on the visible components and not some variables that shadow them?  Without code it's hard to tell where your error lies.

Comment: actually, `doLayout()` on the container which has some size should work, too.

Comment: Maybe, but if you read the API is says you should not use doLayout() directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I finally found the problem, it was because my JPanel was not displayed yet, but after initiating all the elements, I could get a correct size of the panels.

Comment: PS: I forgot to tell. My program is as follows: MainWindow contains different JPanels. I want to edit the amount of grid rows after the MainWindow (which contains a frame) / frame is resized, what method would be the best to use? (I am not familiar with actions that are triggered after resizing) Thanks!